# Angularjs: how to Call method in Controller while submitting the Form

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Actually In my form page of Angularjs, have two submit buttons i.e In one field set i have one button for update and another button at the outside of all field sets for submission of whole page.

**Code**

```
         <form ....... data-ng-submit="Register()">
           <fieldset>
                   ............
                   .............
            <div data-ng-submit="update()">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update Vehicle</button>
            </div>
           </fieldset>
           <fieldset> .........</fieldset>
         </form>
```

After submission of form to the ctrl

```
.ctrl(function(){

 **we have two methods in it.......**

        $scope.update=function(){
          }

         $scope.register=function(){
          }
        }
```

While updating the fieldset it goes to **register method** and its executes the logic in it.

how to format the data-ng-submit="update()", such that it will call the update() method in Controller

Comment: do you mean use ng-click="update();" on that button?

Comment: yaa, while update() is inner submit button and register is outer whole form submit button

Comment: A form can only have one submit type button so I suggest just using ng-click on the other button then.  Or maybe ng-form to have a nested form within a form?

Comment: Just add two different buttons with 2x different click events. One calls update, one calls register.